# Laravel installation on NGINX

Tags: laravel, nginx, digital-ocean

I've created a droplet in www.digitalocean.

I've installed NGINX, PHP5 and MYSQL. So far so good.

I've setup Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts):

- zzzz.com

[image]

If I go to the browser and type zzzz.com it will display what I have in:

- /var/www/zzzz.com/html/index.html

But now I've added Laravel. And supposedly I should see the laravel home page when I go to my http:// server_name

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: Is your nginx configured to use PHP?

Comment: Yes. I have a php file in zzzz.com and it works. I run sudo apt-get install nginx php5-fpm php5-cli php5-mcrypt git before installing laravel

Comment: "And supposedly I should see the laravel home page when I go to my http:// server_name" -- so what are you getting instead? Errors, blank page ?